# How to capture windows message from the up/down button of a CDateTimeCtrl control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using a `CDateTimeCtrl`, along with a callback field, in my dialog application. All works well as intended but I want to capture the windows message when the up-down button ( looks a lot like the spin control) of the `CDateTimeCtrl` is clicked without success. Spy++ reported the class of the up-down button to be msctls_updown32. Spy++ message log offer no clue either. How do I capture the mouse click messages from this up-down control ( looks like an OLE control to me)?

**Edited:** : I've tried handling the `UDN_DELTAPOS` message like so but still unable to capture the message from `CMyTimeCtrl`.

```
class CMyTimeCtrl : public CDateTimeCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyTimeCtrl)
public:
    CMyTimeCtrl();
    virtual ~CMyTimeCtrl();

protected:
    int m_msec;
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    afx_msg void OnDtnFormat(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDtnFormatquery(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDtnWmkeydown(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDeltaposSpin(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyTimeCtrl, CDateTimeCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY(WM_NOTIFY, UDN_DELTAPOS, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDeltaposSpin)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMAT, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnFormat)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMATQUERY, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnFormatquery)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_WMKEYDOWN, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnWmkeydown)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: Why would that be meaningful? It seems awkward to want to respond to some changes but not respond to other changes in the same way. What's the problem you're ultimately looking to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable: Using DTS_TIMEFORMAT format, I am displaying milliseconds also. I can change the time in milliseconds, by capturing DTN_FORMAT, & DTN_FORMATQUERY , using keyboard but I need to use the up-down buttons as well.

Comment: @IInspectable: Custom callback field values don't seem to work with up-down controls.

Comment: The spinner is probably a child of the date-time control, and sends its notifications (usually `WM_NOTIFY` with `UDN_DELTAPOS` notification) to the control, not to the dialog. If you want to see those messages, you'd probably need to subclass the control, or implement your own custom control derived from `CDateTimeCtrl`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Tried to capture the UDN_DELTAPOS notification from my extended class but still it won't buzz.

Comment: Have you reviewed this discussion? http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/8ed526bfa4d686bd.htm

Comment: Andhave you reviewed this other discussion? https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/hFJvpSqg/problems-overriding-cdatetimectrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, with the guidance from the comment section I manage to resolve my issue. In the message map I made an error, corrected as shown below. Now it's working fine. In my resource section, the `IDC_STATIC` value is `1000`:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyTimeCtrl, CDateTimeCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY(UDN_DELTAPOS, IDC_STATIC, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDeltaposSpin)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMAT, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnFormat)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_FORMATQUERY, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnFormatquery)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(DTN_WMKEYDOWN, &CMyTimeCtrl::OnDtnWmkeydown)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: Perhaps flesh out your answer with references to the relevant articles that helped you? And, where appropriate add a quiation of the the information in that article was was beneficial to you?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: The reference articles posted by you helped me in resolving my issue. Thanks